# Issue with "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093] "

Tags: mysql

I have been stuck with the warning message for some time already and have not been able to figure it out.

```
<a href="works.php? TotalCompletedTasks =3">Tasks under 2</a>
    <?php

    $stmt = $con->prepare("v.MemberID, v.VisitingNumber, count(CompletedTaskID) as TotalCompletedTasks
from Visits v join CompletedTasks c
on v.VisitingNumber = c.VisitingNumber
where TotalCompletedTasks<:TotalCompletedTasks");
$stmt->bindParam(': TotalCompletedTasks', $_GET['TotalCompletedTasks'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bindParam(': TotalCompletedTasks', $_GET['TotalCompletedTasks'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

should be:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':TotalCompletedTasks', $_GET['TotalCompletedTasks'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

That is, you have an extraneous space in your parameter name.